# HTACCESS issue, regular expression error?

Tags: .htaccess

i have a little problem with my .htaccess. Any suggestion?

RewriteRule vendita/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=1&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&regione=$1&land=$1_vendita [L]

RewriteRule vendita/([^/]+)/pag-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$2&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&regione=$1&land=$1_vendita [L]

RewriteRule vendita/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=1&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&provincia=$2&land=$2_vendita [L]

RewriteRule vendita/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/pag-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$3&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&provincia=$2&land=$2_vendita [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/vendita/?$ index.php?page=1&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&comune=$1&land=$1_vendita [L]

RewriteRule ([^/]+)/vendita/pag-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$2&ris_pagina=15&tipo=VENDITA&comune=$1&land=$1_vendita [L]

---

EXAMPLES

Url request: http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo/       ---> NOT WORKING :(

Url request: http://www.mysite.com/milano/vendita/pag-2/    ---> NOT WORKING :(

Comment: are you missing something simple like RewriteEngine On ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the regex with `([a-z]+)` for letters and `([0-9]+)` for numbers it will avoid the collides between different rules.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have extraneous ? characters at the end of all your regex patterns.

```
vendita/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

will not match

```
http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo
http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo?
http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo/
http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo/?a=true
```

it will match

```
http://www.mysite.com/vendita/lombardia/bergamo/?
```

try

```
^vendita/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

Comment: I think the question mark is to indicate that the previous character is optional, as in the final trailing slash that is not always there (but sometimes is).